# Scrape Data from Web, Cycling through Dropdowns, Slim Down Data

Tags: vba, excel

Below is where I what I have currently for what I am trying to accomplish. I am looking to scrape seasonal data from my fantasy baseball league. The code below cycles through every season and every team but the data comes out pretty messy. What I need to do now is clean up the data in to clean columns. Also, since the team and season is not attached to the player statistics, I need to make an extra column to list the team name and season. Does anyone have any input?

```
Sub Extract()


Dim IE As Object, obj As Object
Dim League As Object
Dim links, link
Dim dict As Object
Dim s As Integer
Dim t As Integer


Set IE = CreateObject("internetexplorer.application")

IE.Visible = True
IE.navigate ("http://whatifsports.com/hbd/Pages/Main/WorldRedirect.aspx?id=37")

WaitFor IE

IE.navigate ("http://whatifsports.com/HBD/Pages/World/Statistics.aspx")

WaitFor IE

For s = 1 To 36

s = CStr(s)

IE.document.getelementsbyname("ctl00$ctl00$ctl00$Main$PageOptionsPlaceHolder$PageOptionsPlaceHolder$SeasonDropDown$SeasonDropDown")(0).Value = s

For t = 1 To 32

IE.document.getelementsbyname("ctl00$ctl00$ctl00$Main$PageOptionsPlaceHolder$PageOptionsPlaceHolder$FranchiseDropDown$FranchiseDropDown")(0).selectedindex = t
IE.document.forms(0).submit

WaitFor IE

IE.ExecWB 17, 0
IE.ExecWB 12, 0

lastRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
Range("A" & lastRow).Select
ActiveSheet.PasteSpecial Format:="HTML", link:=False, DisplayAsIcon:=False,     NoHTMLFormatting:=True

WaitFor IE

Next t

Next s

End Sub

Sub WaitFor(IE As Object)
While IE.readyState <> 4
    DoEvents
Wend
End Sub
```

Comment: You said, "the data comes out pretty messy". What does the data look like? Add columns for team and season sounds reasonable, where do you get this?

Comment: In the code, it cycles through the season number with integer "s", and cycles through the team with integer "t". There is text for the team name listed in the dropdown. The data comes out messy because I only have the ability to copy the entire webpage and paste it one after another. I either have to delete rows or copy only the selection of specific data.

Comment: Have you tried [this method](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wZ6Ff--QCEo)  of getting data from a website?

Comment: Yes, this method does not recognize the table I wish to extract. I was only able to copy the page in its entirety.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to create a [parser](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parsing).

Once your data cleanly fits into a given set of columns, then you can add the extra columns on the end fairly simply.

You are currently posting your clean table to the range starting at the first blank row in column A. Let's assume your table is 10 columns wide. You can then add the team number and season number with the following:

```
Range(cells(lastRow, 11), cells(cells(lastRow, 10).end(xldown).row, 11)) = "Team " & t & ", Season " & s
```

To get the team name, I would use an array instead of trying to read it from the webpage's dropdown listing every time. I'm going to recommend this for two reasons. 1) I have no source information to work with on this. 2) I would think it's a safe assumption that the list of team names will not change much during a given season that you will be using this.

```
Dim strTeamNames as variant
strTeamNames = Array("", "Team 1", "Team 2", "Team 3", ..., "Team 32")
Range(cells(lastRow, 11), cells(cells(lastRow, 10).end(xldown).row, 11))  = strTeamName(t) & ", Season " & s
```

Comment: If I add columns after parsing the data, it would be rather difficult to attach a team and season to each player. Also, I am having difficulty doing the parsing.

Comment: You didn't show any parsing code in your question. Can you please add that?

Comment: I could accomplish the parsing ok if I could just paste the season number and team name or team number beside the player data I am pasting.

Comment: It sounds like you are pasting an entire table at a time and are having difficulty adding a new column to the end of that range. Is that correct?

Comment: I could do that easily through the recorder, I just don't know where to begin to paste the season and team beside the player statistics dynamically.